# How to use move_base?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ! We team want to develop a UAV recently , and we decide to use move_base in our car's computer . But we meet many questions . Our car equipped a HDL-32E LIDAR , a GPS device . I can understand the structure of Navigation conceptually. [structure](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=overview_tf.png) But we still do not know :

1. how to use GPS data into the move_base . We plan to input a goal GPS position to the car's computer , but we do not find the interface to input .
2. Is the map_server necessary ? I think it is not useful to us ?

Could you give me some advices ?
Thank you very much !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189588/how-to-use-move_base-?/) by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization package for integrating GPS. move_base does not perform any sort of localization/estimation itself.

map_server is necessary when you're loading a pre-created map.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-10**:
We do not need to load a pre-created map , our car aims to run in a wide range , we do not know how to deal with the map_server .

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-11**:
if you don't need it, you don't have to use it. Take a look at 3.3.2 in http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup. The navigation stack is fairly flexible, and you should experiment with your setup in gazebo or similar.